# using iptables to prevent RST related to a specific port

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, tcp

I have a program which uses libpcap to capture incoming TCP SYN packets,  these SYN packets are destined for a specific port.

But I have no tcp listening socket for that port, so in practice, the OS Kernel(it is the kernel or the tcp stack? I'm not sure, can anyone tell me) will issue a RST to the source ip of the TCP SYN.

now I want to prevent the RST, I don't want the RST to be sent to the source ip.  I think maybe iptables can do this?
so how to set the rules with iptables to prevent these RSTs (which are triggered by incoming TCP SYN for a specific port)?

if there are other better solutions, that's better!
thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to break the TCP protocol ?

Comment: I'm doing a research work, which requires this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather basic inbound blocking setup is this:

```
# Set default policy to 'drop everything'
iptables -P INPUT DROP
# Allow lo traffic
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# Allow icmp
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
# Allow packets sent in response to an outgoing connection
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# Allow outgoing connections
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

This should drop all attempts of establishing a connection to your host.

If you want to be more specific, try adding one of these:

```
# Block request from being handled further by the TCP stack
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport <port> -j DROP
# Send an ICMP 'administratively prohibited' response
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport <port> -j REJECT
# Don't send any RESETs upon a request to this port
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -o <outgoing interface> --sport <port> --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
```

Comment: ah, I got it, you mean I can still capture the incoming tcp SYN using libpcap or tcpdump. Just they are not delivered to the TCP stack, so the TCP stack won't issue a RST, is it right?

Comment: Correct. libpcap intercepts packets earlier.